# Cancelled meeting field in outlook 2010 calendar list view

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, calendar, meetings

In general I want to delete all cancelled meetings from calendar. I am not the organizer.

I thought I could use list custom view but I was not able to find the field which would show "cancelled" meeting status.

Is there such field at all? I mean, is it available for the user because internally it obviously exists?

Answer (score 0):

You should not have any to display in a view.

http://www.outlook-tips.net/tips/tip-227-identifying-canceled-meeting-requests/

"Tip 227: Identifying Canceled Meeting Requests
Outlook doesn't support canceling meetings or appointments; you're expected to delete them when they are cancelled."

Office Outlook (2010) - How do I remove a canceled meeting? http://kb1.med.cornell.edu/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=1245210

If you did not remove at the time you received the cancellation notice, then try searching your calendar for "Canceled:".